# Printing pages on different Browsers

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, printing

I'm encountering a lot of problems with printing on a rather huge website we are working on.

The problem is there are issues in FF, IE etc... that appear only when printing.

The workflow is like this: I click a print button on the page, a popup opens with different template and styles and the window.print command is triggered.

**MY POSSIBLE SOLUTION:**

**When the popup opens, I will render the entire DOM in a canvas element and then put it back in page as a png file, and then trigger the print action.**

*Is this a feasible solution?*

Comment: Probably not feasible.  You can try something like the html2canvas library, but a large and more complex website will probably not exactly convert: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this in two ways:

## Browser extension

Writing an extension for the browser(s) (at least Chrome and FireFox) will allow you to grab the current content as a bitmap you can use with canvas.

This is probably the fastest option as the screen snapshot is created internally. Though, I am not sure if the browser snapshots client window or the full document so this need to be determined.

## Simulate the DOM tree

There are libraries such as [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and [canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) that simulates the DOM tree and tries to render an approximate representation of the web page.

There a couple of things to notice with this:

- It's relatively slow
- You may run into cross-origin restrictions in relation to images (work around is to use an image proxy)
- You cannot get content of "foreign objects" (Flash, Java etc.)
- It is not 100% accurate (if this matters)

When you have a snapshot one way or the other the other things should be straight forward. Just remember that users have different printers, drivers and resolutions and you may not be able to produce identical results cross-over as you are also dependent on the browser's own print implementation.

Comment: About the chrome browser extension option you mention:  Is that using the captureVisibleTab method of the chrome.tabs API or have you discovered a different hook in chrome that generates page images?  If you’ve discovered another API hook, would you share…Thanks!   :)

Comment: What I need is a solution available for all the browsers. But that's interesing.      I knew about canvas2image and html2canvas. I'll try using that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

provide special css for print view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

in which for everything you dont want to print use something like:

```
#qqq, .#aaa, #header, ...., ...., .banner{
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

so you leave only content you want to see printed. In this case visitor or you dont need to use special print popup version. Just click print.

example: http://viliusle.github.io/miniPaint/ - only canvas will be printed.

Comment: this method is not feasible for me, time-wise, there's a lot of content types there, and to do for each and every one of them a print style refactoring it would take a lot of time.   Print sheets are already done, but FF has some problems with floats and position relative, and creates a new blank page at the beginning of each document. Plus other issues in IE's

Comment: for me its fastest way. Anyway you can try hiding all divs, tables, td, p, and then unhide content block. "there's a lot of content" -  i think you misunderstood it, first you hide main blocks like header, footer, ads, sidebar, these will hide lots of elements, unless html is not well formated/structured.

Comment: HTML is not well formatted, we're working on a Drupal 6 code base for a huge project, even I hide the outer elements, the structure of what needs to be printed is pretty complex, and there's a lot of content types which would need that treatment. I'll try html2canvas next week, if everything else fails, heavy refactoring of the existing print stylesheets.